# Is it ok to use controller and graphql resolver together in nestJs?

Tags: nestjs

For my next project I would like to use Graphql inside the FrontEnd. Furthermore this project should also offer a Rest-Api.
Now I have discovered this extremely great framework "nestjs", where it is theoretically possible to combine a Graphql endpoint and a rest endpoint.
Unfortunately I can't find anything in the documentation if this can lead to problems. Is the following code usable without problems?

Artikel controller:

```
@Controller('article')
@Resolver('Article')
export class ArticleController {
    constructor(private articleService: ArticleService){}

    @Get()
    @Query(returns => CArticle)
    async Article() {
     const dbElement=await this.articleService.getById("xy");
     return dbElement;
    }
}
```

Article module:

```
@Module({
    controllers:[ArticleController],
    providers:[ArticleService,ArticleController]
})
export class ArticleModule {}
```

Comment: Not going to provide an answer, but currently I am doing the same with nestjs, purely as a test. It seems to work great atm.

Comment: I am looking to do a similar thing with a current project.  I've rolled out the graphql portion but now have requests from team to build some more traditional REST endpoints for some use cases.  I'll let you know what i come up with.

Comment: any updates on your experiences?

Comment: I have answered the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As **this would work in this specific example**, it may not work well in other use cases you may reach.

In my experience with using both Rest and gRPC - there are eventually different things that the controllers need to take care of.

I would **highly recommend having dedicated controllers/resolvers for each API** - with these taking care of API entry (i.e. authenticating, taking care of context) and having the Business Logic in a separate Provider.

So your example would look like so:

Article.controller.ts:

```js
@Controller('article')
export class ArticleController {
    constructor(private articleService: ArticleService){}

    @Get()
    async Article() {
     return this.articleService.getById("xy");
    }
}
```

Article.resolver.ts:

```js
@Resolver('Article')
export class ArticleResolver {
    constructor(private articleService: ArticleService){}

    @Query(returns => CArticle)
    async Article() {
     return this.articleService.getById("xy");
    }
}
```

Article.module.ts:

```js
@Module({
    controllers:[ArticleController, ArticleResolver],
    providers:[ArticleService]
})
export class ArticleModule {}
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand nestjs now, there should be no problems, as the decorators do not change the code but only create new code.